# How to increase heap size for sesame store from the cmd permanently?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, heap-memory, sesame

Could some one please advise me on:
(a) How to identify the current heapsize.
(b) how to increase the heapsize.

Unfortunately the current topics seems to be very vague to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell the current heap size for Sesame by accessing the Sesame server via a browser (e.g. http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/ ) and clicking 'System' in the left-hand menu. It will show the memory currently in use and the maximum heap size.

To increase the heap size, the easiest way is just to allocate a larger heap to Tomcat itself. Have a look at the [Tomcat FAQ entry](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory) on how to do that, or do a Google search, there's tons of helpful Howtos on this topic ([here's one](http://www.techiepark.com/tutorials/how-to-increase-heap-size-for-tomcat/)).